# 正規表現を使って、URL文字列から、ハッシュは残しつつクエリパラメータのみ除外することはできますか？

Tags: 正規表現

例えば、こんなURLがあった場合
`https://www.example.com/test/?q=test&s=test`
`https://www.example.com/hoge/?q=foo&s=faa#hoge`

クエリパラメータのみを除外して、以下のURLとハッシュは抽出したい。
`https://www.example.com/test/`
`https://www.example.com/hoge/#hoge`

これを正規表現で実現することはできますでしょうか？
アドバイスいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 質問に、正規表現を使うツールや言語を明示すれば回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: URL に使われる `#` は通常「アンカー」と呼びます。 / ハッシュはあくまで Twitter 等での呼称ですね。

Comment: `#`以下の正式名称は「フラグメント」です(RFC 3986)。「アンカー」でも「ハッシュ」でも通じるので好きに呼んで構わないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

- `#` はフラグメント開始以外には現れない
- `#` より前の一番最初の `?` はクエリの開始

  - ただし、クエリ内やフラグメント内に`?`が現れることがある

この性質を利用すれば正規表現置換で簡単に実現できるでしょう。例えば

`^([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$`

この正規表現で1番目と3番目の グループを残せば希望の動作になるかと思います。

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) にURIの正規表現が載っています。参考になると思います。

```
      ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
       12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
```

また、プログラミング言語によってはURL/URIを表現するライブラリが用意されているので、正規表現を使うよりそちらを使うほうがわかりやすいコードになるかも知れません。

Comment: +1: URL や URI の規約は意外と複雑なので、メンテナンス性を高めるためにもライブラリが使える場合はライブラリを使った方が良いと考えています。ライブラリの記述がある点に +1 です。